# $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ open and $D \subset U$ open and dense $\implies \lambda(D) = \lambda(U)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

*This is not a homework exercise!*

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be and open subset and $D \subset U$ open and dense in $U$.
>   Can we conclude that $\lambda(D) = \lambda(U)$?

Here, $\lambda$ denotes the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

This condition is trivially true for any $\lambda$-null set $U$.
For the general case, I think this boils down to the question whether a $\lambda$-non null set $A$ such that $\lambda(A) > 0$ has a non-empty interior: $\mathring{A} \neq \emptyset$.
Since then, we could argue that $\lambda(U \setminus D) = 0$, which implies the highlighted proposition.

I´d be grateful for a proof or counterexample for any of the two statements.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Here is a one dimensional example that can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $U$ be the open unit ball and let $q_k$ be an enumeration of the rational points in $U$. Let $D$ be the union of sets $B(q_k,\epsilon_k)$ where $\epsilon_k$ is chosen so that the set lies in $U$ and $\epsilon_k \le L {1 \over 2^{k+1}}$. For any $L>0$ we see that $D$ is open and dense, but $\lambda D \le L$.

Comment: @copper.hat That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: $\lambda D \le \sum_k \lambda B(q_k,\epsilon_k) \le \sum_k 2L {1 \over 2^{k+1}} = 2L$. (My constants might be off by a factor.) In any event, $L>0$ is arbitrary and

Comment: You can always choose the $\epsilon_k>0$ as small as you want... The basic message is that denseness and measure are 'independent'.

Comment: Check fat Cantor set.

Comment: @copper.hat Please post your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let $\tau_d := \frac{\pi^{\frac{d}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2} + 1\right)}$ the volume of the $d$-dimensional unit sphere and $\Gamma(x)$ the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).
Then, $\lambda(B(x,r)) = \tau_d r^d$.

As @copperhat suggests in the comments, a counterexample for the first statement goes as follows:

> Let $L > 0$ be arbitrary.
>   Let $U$ be the open unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $(q_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{Q} \cap U$ an enumeration of all rational points in $U$.
>   Then, let $$D := \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B(q_k, \varepsilon_k),$$ where for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the number $\varepsilon_k > 0$ is chosen so that
>   $$
> B(q_k, \varepsilon_k) \subset U
> \qquad \text{and} \qquad \varepsilon_k < \sqrt[d]{\frac{L}{2^{k - 1} \cdot \tau_d}}.
> $$
>   Then,
>   $$
> \lambda(D)
> \le \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda\left(B(q_n, \varepsilon)\right)
> = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \tau_d \varepsilon_{k}^{d}
> < \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \tau_d \cdot \frac{L}{2^{k - 1} \cdot \tau_{d}} 
> = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{L}{2^{k - 1}} 
> = L.
> $$

Therefore, we can get $\lambda(D)$ to be as small as we want, and it will be still open as union of open sets an dense since it contain all $q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap U$.

@Will_M. gives a great counterexample for the second proposition: the [fat cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set).