# Baire's Theorem: Examples for open dense subsets

Tags: metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, baire-category

> **Theorem (Baire):** Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $(D_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a family of open dense subsets of $X$. Then $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} D_n$ is also dense in $X$.

This is the first theorem we proved in our functional analysis lecture and we were told it's essential for the proofs of fundamental theorems of functional analysis.

> My question is simpler: I'm struggling to find open dense subsets in a "normal" metric space.

@copper_hat's comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182669/u-subset-mathbbrd-open-and-d-subset-u-open-and-dense-implies-lambda?noredirect=1#comment6550704_3182669) suggests uninting $\varepsilon$-balls with rational centres but are there other good examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Take $(S_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ affine subspaces i.e. $S_i = V_i + p_i$ with $V_i$ a linear subspace and $p_i$ a point. Then each $S_i$ is closed and has no interior (this is a fun excersice of linear algebra / functional analysis). Thus **each $S_i^c$ is open and moreover, it is dense**:

$$
\overline{S_i^c} = (S_i^°)^c = \emptyset^c = X. 
$$

Thus $\bigcap_{i \geq 1}S^c_i$ is dense. In the former calculation, we showed that the complement of a closed set with no interior is open and dense. Note that the converse also holds, thus giving the following equivalent formulation of Baire's theorem,

> **Theorem(Baire):** let $X$ be a complete metric space and $(F_n)_{n \geq 1} \subset X$ be a sequence of closed sets in with empty interior. Then $\bigcup_{n \geq 1} F_n$ has empty interior.

In particular, this says that we can't write $X$ as the countable union of closed sets with no interior. Thus, in this setting, let's rephrase the original comment:  each affine subspace is closed and has no interior, thus their union cannot be $\mathbb{R}^n$. This proves:

> **Proposition**. An  euclidean space cannot be written as a countable union of affine subspaces.

In general this is the type of argument Baire's theorem is used for. Another useful consequence is that *if* $X$ is written as a countable union of closed sets, then some of them has to have non-empty interior. This for example allows us to prove the principle of uniform boundedness, one of the key results you will study.

As a final remark, the example given here lets you prove that

> **Proposition.** Given $n,m \geq 1$ there is a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of size $m$ such that any subset of $n+1$ points of $A$ is affinely independent.

There are quite simpler approaches, but let's go with the one that uses Baire.

*Proof*. We can fix $n$ and use induction on $m$. The base case is trivial. As for the inductive step, we have $A$ of size $m$ with all its subsets of size $n+1$ affinely independent. It suffices to see that we can add a point to $A$ such that this keeps holding. Suppose not: then, for any point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we pick, $A \cup \{p\}$ must contain an affinely dependent subset $S_p \subset A \cup \{p\}$ of $n+1$ elements. Note also that $p \in S$, because otherwise $S \subset A$ and thus $S$ would be affinely independent by inductive hypothesis. If we write $S_p = T_p \cup \{p\}$, then $S_p$ being affinely dependent says that in particular, $p$ is contained in the affine subspace generated by the points of $T_p$. To sum up: for any point $p$, there is a subset $T \subset A$ such that $p \in V_T$ where $V_T$ is the (affine) subspace generated by $V$. In particular,

$$
\mathbb{R}^n \subset \bigcup_{T \subset A, |T| = n}V_T
$$

which is absurd because the right hand side is a countable (it is finite, even, as $A$ is finite) union of closed sets of empty interior, and **by Baire's theorem** this implies it has empty interior. The contradiction comes from supposing that we can't add a point to $A$ without it losing its properties. Hence a point *can* be added to $A$, which is now of size $m+1$. This completes the inductive step (and the proof) $\square$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\in A$, then $X\setminus \{a\}$ is an open dense subset (as far as singleton are closed).

Comment: Note that this remark comes in handy if you want to prove that a countable dense set (like $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$) cannot be written as a countable intersection of open sets

Comment: This is true iff $a$ is not an isolated point of $X$.